# Setting properly sidebar in frontend design

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, sidebar

I've been trying to make a website layout, but I simply cannot. I cannot post image itself because I don't have enough reputations.

I have sidebar that should be fixed and stay as long as I scroll vertically. Next to it should be area with the main content of the page, which is vertically scrollable.

Now I've seen few similar questions here, but nothing seems to be working for me, because when I scale window, it just messes up. So how should I do this? Will columns help? What divs should I have? And what would be the CSS code for them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to be able to help you, it is requested that you post your code along with your question.

Comment: Or even better, reproduce your problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use `position: absolute` to position the elements.

([Demo with filler text](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/y2qn0huj/1/))

```css
*,*::before,*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 225px;
  background: rgb(50, 150, 250);
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 225px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(235, 245, 255);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
    /* Side bar */
</div>
<div class="right">
    /* Content */
</div>
```